# typescript: Importing modules from outside path

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following structure (redacted):

```
workspace
|- thegame
 |- node_modules
 | package.json
 | bs-config.json
 |- src
  | tsconfig.json
  |- app
   | game.model.ts (<--  here I would like to import game-engine)
|- game-engine
 |- dist (after the local build)
 | package.json
 | tsconfig.json
 |- lib
  | index.ts (the actual engine module)
```

I run the application (Angular2) in the "thegame" path with "npm start".

What should I add to the thegame/src/tsconfig.json so that I could do following in the game.model.ts?

```
import { Engine } from 'game-engine';
```

I have tried to symlink the "game-engine" to "thegame/node_modules" but when I run the project with lightserve it gives "404 GET /game-engine"

I want to develop the engine separated from the web application. I am also interested in any other hints how to achieve this.

The project is based on Angular 2 Quickstart at https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: What you should add depends on your loader or bundler. What do you use? SystemJS? Webpack 2? Also, what package manager are you using? NPM? JSPM? Yarn?

Comment: Package manager is npm. I am not sure about loader. This is based on the Angular 2 Quickstart: https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: Boo, I hate that quickstart. Anyway, what you need to do is run `cd workspace\thegame` -> `npm install ../game-engine`

Comment: Thanks for updating answer, but `tsc` is not a loader it is the TypeScript compiler's command line interface. Based on the link, your loader is SystemJS, an excellent module loader.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed with the game-engine (I edited the question and added the lib/index.ts file to the structure tree). I changed the import to "game-engine/lib" and it compiled. But when I run it I get "404 GET /game-engine/lib"

Comment: Go to `src/systemjs.config.js` and add an entry for `"game-engine"` to the `map` section. Is `"game-engine"` a module you have written? Those starter kits make such poor use of SystemJS, it is quite sad, for example, you can easily consume any module directly as source or in pre-compiled form, but they don't set you up with a transpiler....

Comment: Yes "game-engine" is a module I will write at the same time I will write the web app "thegame".

Comment: How do you plan to compile it and where will the output go? NVM I see that info in your question

Comment: Go to src/systemjs.config.js and add an entry for "game-engine" to the map section. It will be probably be `"game-engine": "game-engine/dist/index.js"`.

Comment: I have been following this guide: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/writing-a-node-module-in-typescript.html

Comment: Seems reasonable at a glance. Try what I suggested in my last comment it should work provided you have compiled game-engine.

Comment: I did the "Prepare for publishing" stuff also and got to use import statement `from 'game-engine'`. So it compiles fine, but the running now gives me `404 GET /game-engine/dist/index.js`

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid. It needs to be `"game-engine": "npm:game-engine/dist/index.js"` in the `"map"` configuration

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! Can you format these steps as an answer, so that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an Angular Quick Start kit that uses SystemJS and NPM as its foundation, and given how you have described your directory layout, you will want to take the following steps.

Open a terminal in `workspace/thegame` and run

```
npm install --save ../game-engine
```

this will tell npm to install the package from that location on disk as a standard dependency of your `thegame` application.

Now we just need to tell SystemJS where the newly added dependency is located. SystemJS uses explicit configuration (as opposed to a recursive directory walk) to locate dependencies. This is a *good* thing, but since we are using NPM instead of something like JSPM, we need to manually set this up.

Fortunately, it amounts to a single line added to the `systemjs.config.js` file which, as per the Quick Start, should be located in the `src` sub-directory of your `thegame` directory.

Add the following to the `"map"` property of the configuration object:

```
"game-engine": "npm:game-engine/dist/index.js"
```

Ultimately the file will look like

```
SystemJS.config({
  paths: {
    "npm:": "node_modules/"
  },
  map: {
    "game-engine": "npm:game-engine/dist/index.js",
    "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
    // etc.
  }
  // etc.
});
```